# How do I configure my M-AUDIO Fast Track Pro in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, system-preferences, m-audio

I have a USB audio interface device called the [M-AUDIO Fast Track Pro](http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/FastTrackPro.html) which works wonderfully on my Windows machine; I'd like to get it working on my Linux machine. I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04 "Natty Narwhal". When I plugged the Fast Track Pro into the USB port, it *did* automatically detect it.

When I bring up the Sound Preferences, I see "M-Audio Fast Track Pro" listed under the "Hardware" tab. This is good news. However, it lists the device as being only an "Analog Stereo Output" device instead of an "Analog Stereo Duplex" device. This is not good news. I need it to be a duplex device, because my main purpose in using it is to record. In other words, I need its **input** capabilities -- perhaps more than I need its output capabilities.

Is there some way I can manually go in and set it to be identified with the "Duplex" profile instead of the purely "Output" profile? For instance, is there a configuration file I can edit as root to do this?

Comment: I have a Fast Track Pro on Mac OS X, and when I don't have the driver installed, it appears as *two* audio devices rather than one, one with 2 in and one with 4 out. Is it possible that you are getting a similar result and the input device might be available but buried somewhere, or hidden by the identically-named output device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same situation happening for my M-AUDIO Quattro. The short answer is: M-Audio and Digidesign are not interested in people using old hardware.

This said, most legacy (USB 1.1) USB sound cards are unfortunately found as output-only sound cards by Ubuntu. Information to create your own drivers is not available through M-AUDIO or Digidesign.